# Wordpress: How to locate and edit .php files?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using **free** version of wordpress to create a website like mysite.wordpress.com

I need to edit many of the .php files to make changes to it. But where can i find them? The wordpress admin pages contain no such information.

Is this not possible in this scenario?
OR 
Do i need to download Wordpress and host on my own to start editing wordpress .php files?

Comment: Log in to your wordpress file, and should find the files in the control pannel.

Comment: Wait, there's a something-other-than-free version of WordPress?  :)

Comment: As I understand one of the limitations of wordpress.com is that it doesn't allow you to edit your theme. You need to selfhost your site.

Comment: CHao, user850010, php NoOb> So, even with Paid Version of Wordpress (i will not be self-hosting) - i cannot edit .php files? That was my intended question. So a mere upgrade to paid version is not enough?

Comment: @Jasper: WordPress is open source.  Even the free version lets you edit the PHP files, *if* you have your own copy of WP.  But i highly doubt wordpress.com has thousands of copies of the same files; that'd make WP updates a bitch and a half.  So everyone's probably sharing it.  And if you're sharing the software that runs your site with a hundred other sites, do you really want any of them to be able to screw around with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress.com

> All the basic and original features of the site are free-to-use.
>   However, some features (including CSS editor, domain mapping, Domain
>   Registration, Removal of Ads, Website Redirection, Video Upload, and
>   storage upgrades) are available as paid options.

If you want to modify Wordpress source code, you have to host it yourself.

Comment: Niels B> So, even with Paid Version of Wordpress (i will not be self-hosting) - i cannot edit .php files?

Comment: It sure seems so. It would be infeasible for wordpress.com to maintain the service, if each blog had it's own customized codebase.

Comment: Niels B> What about plugins? Can i use Plugins only in hosted version, or a a Paid version will allow me to use Plugins (without self-hosting)?

Comment: @Jasper  I don't know. I don't use their service.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/) page, paid version of wordpress.com only allows you to modify fonts and CSS but not HTML / PHP.

This is what they say on this question:

**Does the Custom Design upgrade let me edit HTML?**

> No. The Custom Design upgrade allows you to edit fonts and CSS only. You can change the
>   appearance of a theme, but not its HTML markup, PHP code, or content.
>   If you require this functionality, please consider moving your blog to
>   a web host that supports theme code modifications,...

Answer (score 0):

WordPress.com edition doesn't offer editing HTML or PHP files.
Yes you need to download and host on your own to customizing them.